# How do I compose a frequency list from unique arrays of different length in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

I have a list of numpy arrays of different lengths, some of which repeat, like so:

```
import numpy as np

multi = [np.array([1, 2, 3]),
      np.array([1, 2]),
      np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
      np.array([1, 2, 3]),
      np.array([1, 2])]
```

From this list, I want a count of the unique arrays (like a histogram over the sequences).

Since numpy arrays are not hashable, I am doing this by converting the arrays to their string representation and using that as a key for grouping with `itertools.groupby` similar to [this method](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15997),

```
import itertools

sorted_strings = sorted([str(p) for p in multi])
groups = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_strings)]
print(groups)
```

The output for this is:

```
[('[1 2 3 4]', 1), ('[1 2 3]', 2), ('[1 2]', 2)]
```

This is correct, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution, or if there is a better way to store this data than in a list of arrays.

Comment: Maybe you could use numpy for it, but honestly since you arrays seems small, unless you have some good reason or use a completely different approach, I would say just use tuples, they are hashable... The string is really a *big* hack and how would you get back to a decent type from there...

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answers and comments! In my application, the sequences are longer, and there are more of them. But since it seems I need to convert the numpy arrays into something hashable anyway, tuples certainly make a lot more sense than strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> Counter(map(tuple, multi)).most_common()
[((1, 2), 2), ((1, 2, 3), 2), ((1, 2, 3, 4), 1)]
```

---

To get least common:

```
>>> Counter(map(tuple, multi)).most_common()[::-1]
[((1, 2, 3, 4), 1), ((1, 2, 3), 2), ((1, 2), 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with a version of Python that doesn't define `collections.Counter`, you could use the method you linked to:

```
 base = sorted(tuple(m) for m in multi)
 G=[(k,len(list(g))) for (k,g) in itertools.groupby(base)]
```

You'd basically transform each array into a tuple (note that the `Counter`-based method relies on the same approach).

Note that you may want to make sure your arrays are sorted, so that `np.array([2,1])` and `np.array([1,2])` are considered equivalent:

```
 base = sorted(tuple(sorted(m)) for m in multi)
```